# Can not import JQuery to a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add the following function to a chrome extension:

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#other" ).autocomplete( {
      source: availableTags,
      minLength: 0
    })
    .focus(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
    })
    ;
  } );
```

But I kept getting the error:

```
counterstring.js:7 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at show_options (VM182 counterstring.js:7)
    at VM182 counterstring.js:81
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at VM182 counterstring.js:78
```

EDIT:

I have updated the manifest file as suggested in the comments, but still getting errors. This is the current version I have:

```
    "content_scripts": [ {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js", "js/jquery-ui.min.js", "js/counterstring.js"]
  }],
    "background": {
        "persistent": true,
        "scripts": ["js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js","js/jquery-ui.min.js","js/background.js","js/counterstring.js"]
      },
    "permissions": [
         "contextMenus",
         "activeTab", 
         "storage"
       ],
```

Now I'm only imported jquery 3.5xxx and  also jquery-ui since I read it is also required for the autocomplete function.

From this I'm still getting the same error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at show_options (VM238 counterstring.js:6)
    at VM238 counterstring.js:80
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at VM238 counterstring.js:77
```

Also, if I tried without importing jquery-ui I get this other error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at show_options (VM274 counterstring.js:6)
    at VM274 counterstring.js:80
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at VM274 counterstring.js:77
```

Which I interpret is it is importing jquery with that code, but still not finding the function I need.

Comment: Looks like the order of the scripts import is reversed. You should be importing Jquery first. https://riptutorial.com/google-chrome-extension/example/9651/multiple-content-scripts-in-the-manifest

Comment: @mwilson how 15 duplicates on less than 10 lines?

Comment: @AndrewHalpern Just changed the order, still getting the same error

Comment: Why are you loading two different versions of jQuery? It usually makes no sense. Also, you can't specify `matches` in `background` section of manifest.json. See the documentation and example extensions.

Comment: The error you are getting without "importing jquery-ui", is because autocomplete seem to be jquery-ui widget. It's expected to fail when "jquery-ui" is missing.

Regarding the errors, it says "Uncaught (in promise)", can you please share the promise part, just in case?

Also don't forget to clear errors in extension's error page before reloading extension as Chrome keeps old errors persistent after extension reload unless old error log is cleaned manually for background page.

Comment: What is the content of `counterstring.js`?